# Structuring a conditional sentence by commata

Tags: grammar, commas, clauses

I have a question on some specific sentence and its punctuation. The sentence in question is:

> [...] Hence, the only relevant information is, if such an unary language part is infinite, and if not, what length has the single
>   unary word it contains.

Is the punctuation in this sentence correct? I somehow have the feeling it sound a little bit odd. Also the clause "the only relevant information is" seems to "float in the air" a little bit. It seems to be missing some part. But I do not know how to alter it such that it would give a more grammatical sentence?

Comment: Yep, it's odd..

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, its content too, or at least quite special. But I more mean the general grammatical structure

Comment: Do you mean "[...] Hence, the only relevant information **exists** if such an unary language part is infinite *[no comma]* **but**, if not, what length has the single unary word it contains."?

Comment: @Greybeard Thanks for your suggestion. But, I more mean it as a case distinction. Like "Consider fruits [...]. Hence, the only relevant information is, if this particular fruit is an apple, or an orange." More like that, does it help?

Comment: @StefanH Ah! "Consider fruits [...]. Hence, the only relevant information is **whether** this particular fruit is an apple *[no comma]* or an orange."

Comment: The commas suggest "parenthetical" phrases, when examination of the apparent semantics indicates that they aren't.

Comment: My attempt at translation:  *Hence, the only relevant question is whether such an unary language part is infinite, and, if not, what is the length of the single unary word it contains.*  (But it still doesn't make much sense.)

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks, yes that sounds better. The content is from a research paper I am writing. Sorry, I know it must sound strange for someone not involved in this particular strand of research. Somehow worse, language has a more formal meaning in it, like programming language. Not related to languages as studied here ;) Btw if you, or any other, like to do so, maybe it would be better to post a full answer, not just a comment.

Comment: @HotLicks And maybe just out of curiosity, why the comma before the "and" and around the "if not"?

Comment: The comma before "and" is a "normal" comma, separating two phrases of essentially equal significance.  The other two are surrounding a "parenthetical phrase".

Comment: Two things stood out for me. (1) Based on the pronunciation of the word, it should be ***a*** *unary*, just like it's ***a*** *unicorn*. (2) The entire part of *if X and if not* is redundant, since it applies to every situation. In short, the entire sentence can simply be *Hence, the only relevant information is what length has the single unary word it contains*. Simplistically, that has only a single comma.

Comment: @JasonBassford Oh yes, thanks. You are totally right about the a/an!  For your omission of the "infinite" part, actually a unary language is a set of sequences over a single symbol. In general, a set could be infinite in different ways, or it could contain a specific number of elements. Like the even numbers, odd numbers vs a set with 1 and 2, or just 5, for example. In this context, what matters is if the set in question is infinite, and it does not matter what specific elements it contains, or if it only contains a single element.  I cannot simply omit the case that it could be infinite.

Comment: @StefanH Oh! The way it's written is ambiguous. I think now that you mean to say *the only relevant information is if such a unary language part is infinite, **or**, if not, what length has the single unary word it contains.* In short, replace **and** with **or**.

Comment: That makes it similar to: *Tell us if the fruit is an orange, **or**, if not, why you bought it.* Assuming I have the correct meaning, I can put all of that into an answer …

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes, that sounds good :) Thanks for all your effort. Means a lot to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments under the question that provided clarification, I am prepared to provide an answer.

---

In looking at the sentence, the main part of my personal confusion was this:

> … the only relevant information is, if such an unary language part is infinite, and if not, …

To me, I interpreted the meaning of the phrase to be equivalent to this:

> The only relevant information is if X, and if not X, then Y.

In short, I took it as a redundancy that could be shortened to simply:

> The only relevant information is Y.

However, it was made clear to me that wasn't the intended meaning of the sentence.

Instead, the problem was with the use of **and** rather than **or**, and it should have been constructed in a manner similar to this:

> I sent you to the store to buy an orange. I see you have a fruit in your bag. *Tell me if it is an orange, or, if not, why you bought something else*.

---

Given that this is the correct interpretation of what had been meant to be expressed, the sentence should be rephrased as follows (I have included some additional small edits):

> Hence, the only relevant information is [] if such **a** unary language part is infinite, **or, if not**, what length has the single unary word it contains.

In short, I did this:

- Removed the comma before *if such*.
- Changed *an unary* to *a unary*
- Changed **and if not** to **or, if not**.

The version of the sentence without notation is:

> Hence, the only relevant information is if such a unary language part is infinite, or, if not, what length has the single unary word it contains.